# Ubuntu computer will not start

Tags: 12.04, boot

My computer with Ubuntu will not start, I get a message

> Stopping system V run level compatibility
>   OK

and computer stops.

Am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

I tried to load Ubuntu off CD both 32 & 64 bit, but then it does not load although BIOS is set to look at CD first to load.

Computer was working fine yesterday.

Same problem on 12.4 LTS 64 bit on reboot from update.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try Easybcd software it is free for home user and install it. open it you will see add new entry click on it go to linux tab add entry click and selcet "swap partition" in it after that click on edit boot menu select the appropriate timeout option and save setting.

if you installed ubuntu inside windows or using wubi then also use this tool and select c:\  drive with "GRUB2" booting options.

Download here:http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml

after starting ubuntu please update it :- sudo apt-get update / upgrade ( try to update all security issue from update package manager )